# It is possible to use the new In-App Review?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

As you may know Google Play in-app review dialog is an upcoming feature

[image]

Here is a working proof of concept app : [IAR Test App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.test.app.inappreview)

I wanted to use this unofficial feature, I did a search and I found this:

[Exploring in-app reviews: part 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ds4l34/exploring_inapp_reviews_part_1/)

But there is no decompiled source code, Can someone share with us a working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play's In-App Reviews is now available [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/in-app-review-api.html).